# 'Go to Folder' disabled from new Finder window

Tags: finder, macos

When I open a new Finder window, i.e. <kbd>⌘ N</kbd> 
I am unable to access the 'Go To Folder' option. (Either via the 'Go' menu, or <kbd>⌘ Shift G</kbd>)

[image]

However, I've noticed the option is available within the Open dialog of another application (e.g. TextEdit).

Is there anyway to make this option available in a new Finder window?

OSX 10.12.1

Answer (score 1):

It's possible the feature has been disabled. You can delete the override using the following:

```
defaults delete com.apple.finder ProhibitGoToFolder && killall -HUP Finder
```

Comment: Unfortunately this fails with:
`Domain (com.apple.finder) not found.
Defaults have not been changed.`